# Create factorial triangle in python

Tags: python, algorithm, factorial

I want to make a triangle for factorial for python which needs to looks like:

```
8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   
8    n   
7    n   n   
6    n   n   n
5    n   n   n   n
4    n   n   n   n   n
3    n   n   n   n   n   n
2    n   n   n   n   n   n   n
1    n   n   n   n   n   n   n   n
```

My code is:

```
import math

def combination(n,m):
    return int((math.factorial(n))/((math.factorial(m))*math.factorial(n-m)))

def main():
    print("|",end='')
    for n in range(8,0,-1):
        print("  ",n,end='')
    print()
    print("--------------------------------------")

    for m in range(8,0,-1):
        print(m,"|",end='')
        for n in range(8,0,-1):
            if(n>=m):
                print(format(combination(n,m),"4d"),end='')
            else:
                print()
main()
```

Please help.

Comment: Combination function calculates values for Pascal's triangle. And I don't see a question. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you printing are unnecessary blank lines. You need to add a `break` statement to the `else` statement. Also add couple of spaces to the first print statement to align the table and add a format statement to the second print statement so that you get a consistent output when the number of the digits of `m` grows.

```
import math

def combination(n,m):
    return int((math.factorial(n))/((math.factorial(m))*math.factorial(n-m)))

def main():
    print("  |",end='')
    for n in range(8,0,-1):
        print(format(n, "4d"), end='')

    print() 
    print("--------------------------------------")

    for m in range(8,0,-1):
        print(m,"|",end='')
        for n in range(8,0,-1):
            if(n>=m):
                print(format(combination(n,m),"4d"),end='')
            else:
                print()
                break
    print()

main()

#   |   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1
# --------------------------------------
# 8 |   1
# 7 |   8   1
# 6 |  28   7   1
# 5 |  56  21   6   1
# 4 |  70  35  15   5   1
# 3 |  56  35  20  10   4   1
# 2 |  28  21  15  10   6   3   1
# 1 |   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1
```